# Creating a table with composite primary key referencing two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a the following table using MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE registrations (
    eventNumber CHAR(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL
        CHECK (EXISTS (SELECT eventNumber FROM events)),
    employeeNumber CHAR(5) UNIQUE NOT NULL 
        CHECK (EXISTS (SELECT employeeNumber FROM employees)),

    PRIMARY KEY(eventNumber , employeeNumber ),

    FOREIGN KEY (eventNumber) REFERENCES eventNumber (employees)
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (employeeNumber ) REFERENCES employeeNumber(employees)
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

However, I get a can't create table error (1005) when I run the command. What might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, I got the REFERENCES statement wrong.

It should in fact read:

```
REFERENCES <table name>(<attribute name>)
```